# How can I encode a string for HTML?

Tags: perl, html-encode

I'm looking for a simple way to HTML encode a string/object in Perl. The fewer additional packages used the better.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "HTML encode"?  Can you give an example input and the desired output?

Comment: What character sets/locales do you have to handle?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Entities) is your friend here.

```
use HTML::Entities;
my $encoded = encode_entities( "foo & bar & <baz>" );
```

Answer (score 31):

When this question was first answered, [HTML::Entities](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities) was the module most people probably used. It's pure Perl and by default will escape the HTML reserved characters `><'"&` and wide characters.

Recently, [HTML::Escape](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::Escape) showed up. It has both XS and pure Perl. If you're using the XS version, it's about ten times faster than [HTML::Entities](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities). However, it only escapes `><'"&` and has no way to change the defaults. Here's the difference with the XS version:

```
Benchmark: timing 10000 iterations of html_entities, html_escape...
html_entities: 14 wallclock secs (14.09 usr +  0.01 sys = 14.10 CPU) @ 709.22/s (n=10000)
html_escape:  1 wallclock secs ( 0.68 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.68 CPU) @ 14705.88/s (n=10000)
```

And here's the fair fight with pure Perl versions on each side:

```
Benchmark: timing 10000 iterations of html_entities, html_escape...
html_entities: 14 wallclock secs (13.79 usr +  0.01 sys = 13.80 CPU) @ 724.64/s (n=10000)
html_escape:  7 wallclock secs ( 7.57 usr +  0.01 sys =  7.58 CPU) @ 1319.26/s (n=10000)
```

You can get these benchmarks in [Surveyor::Benchmark::HTMLEntities](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Surveyor::Benchmark::HTMLEntities). I explain [how I distribute benchmarks](http://www.masteringperl.org/?p=26) using [Surveyor::App](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Surveyor::App).

Comment: Given the fact that `HTML::Entities` looks for wide characters too, the pure Perl fight might not be that fair. It could be interesting to alter the code in the pure Perl version of `HTML::Escape` to include the same cases under its own algorithm and see that fight again.

Answer (score 4):

Which do you need to encode, a string or an object? If it's just a string, then you should just have to worry about encoding issues such as UTF-8, and [CGI::escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) will probably do the trick for you.  If it's an object, you'll need to serialize it first, which opens up a whole new set of issues, but you might want to consider [JSON](http://json.org)-encoding it.

PS. Although since I can't find any recent documentation on this method (it's actually imported from [CGI::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Util) and is marked as "internal"), you should probably use escapeHTML() as daxim points out in his comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#AUTOESCAPING_HTML

Comment: The function is called `escapeHTML`. Proper deeplink: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#AUTOESCAPING_HTML

Comment: @daxim: `CGI::escape` very much exists; it's actually defined in CGI::Util and imported into CGI proper. If you look at the source there are some subtle differences in implementation, which are sadly not well described in the documentation.

Comment: Alright. I'm not able to undo the vote because it is too old.

Comment: @daxim: I've edited the post so you get another crack at that vote :)