# how to put xml string in html table cell using perl

Tags: html, xml, perl

I have xml message in a variable and want to display on browser using table. I tried below but during rendering to browser the actual xml string is not showing.

```
open FH, ">report.html";

my $x=qq(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Soap-ENV:Envelope xmlns:Soap-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:msdwHdr="http://xml.xdft.com/ns/appmw/soap/1.0/header" version="1.1">
 <Soap-ENV:Body>
  <CheckTrade>
   <tradeId>492195</tradeId>
  </CheckTrade>
 </Soap-ENV:Body>
</Soap-ENV:Envelope>);

print FH "<table><tr><td>test</td><td>$x</td></tr></table>";
```

If i run above code and open report.html in browser i am able to see first TD value and in second TD it is showing only 492195 (that is part of tradeid) i want to see complete $x value. I looked at source of html.It is showing same as $x but on browser it is not.

```
______________
test  | 492195 
______|________
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having is the XML document doesn't play nicely in HTML.  All the `<>` characters confuse your browser and thus you're only getting the value of tradeID.  Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105124/21987) for how to encode your XML string before you put it into the HTML document.

Comment: Worked well, Thanks,use HTML::Entities;
my $encoded = encode_entities( $xml );

Answer (score 2):

You could also escape the entire XML string by putting it in a `[CDATA][1]` section:

```
print FH "<table><tr><td>test</td><td><![CDATA[$x]]></td></tr></table>";
```

Of course this works only as long as the SOAP message doesn't itself contain CDATA. If that happens, you will need to break it up: replace the CDATA end marker, `]]>`, in the SOAP message by `]]]><![CDATA[]>` (closing the CDATA section in the middle of the marker and starting a new one, that starts with the end of the marker:

```
$x=~ s{]]>}{]]]><![CDATA[]>}g;
```

or more clearly:

```
 $x=~ s{]]>}                   # CDATA end marker
       {]                      # beginning of the end marker
         ]]>                   # end the first CDATA section
            <![CDATA[          # start a new CDATA section
                     ]>}gx;    # end of the end marker
```

A couple of notes on your Perl style:

- the current best practices are to avoid bareword filehandles, by using lexical ones,
- it's also considered better to use the 3 args form of open, in your case likely with an encoding:

so it's probably better to write this:

```
open( my $fh, '>:utf8', 'report.html') or die "cannot open reports.html: $!";
...
print {$fh} "<table><tr><td>test</td><td><![CDATA[$x]]></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, i will follow the rule.