# Generating HTML code in Perl to display starting HTML code?

Tags: html, perl

Is there a function in PERL (don't care if it's a built-in function or a module-provided function) that will accept a string containing a section of HTML code as it's argument --- and as it's return value provide a string of newly-generated HTML code that, when sent to the browser, will show the user the same HTML code that *originally* was provided to this function as an *argument*?

For example, if the argument provided to this function is

```
<p>This is <em>really</em>
what I call "awesome" & then some.</p>
```

I would like the return-value to be something alone the lines of

```
&lt;p&gt;This is &lt;em&gt;really&lt;/em&gt;<br/>what
I call &quot;awesome&quot; &amp; then some.&lt;/p&gt;
```

So - does there exist a function in Perl that will do this for me?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105092/how-can-i-encode-a-string-for-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice is probably the [`HTML::Escape`](https://p3rl.org/HTML::Escape) module

Use it like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use HTML::Escape 'escape_html';

my $html = <<END_HTML;
<p>This is <em>really</em>
what I call "awesome" & then some.</p>
END_HTML

print escape_html($html);
```

#### output

```
&lt;p&gt;This is &lt;em&gt;really&lt;/em&gt;
what I call &quot;awesome&quot; &amp; then some.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: Okay --- it doesn't HTML-substitute the newline character -- but at least it does everything else I want.

Comment: Wrap it in a pre element (or equivalent CSS) to preserve newlines and multiple whitespace